# Better solution to check elements of one character vector with another character vector using the tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse, string-comparison, purrr

**Hello!**
My goal is to compare two character vectors - the main being synonyms and another mixnames. The string elements in mixnames do not match exactly to what is in synonyms therefore some string comparison is required. My objective is to extract the elements in synonyms that have a something that looks like what is in mixnames. I tried to do this using only the tidyverse but failed. I found a solution that works using base. I know there is a better way, but I can't figure it out....

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.1
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.1
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.1

#Acetometaphin 

synonyms <- c("Pediatrix","Percocet-5","Percocet-Demi","Perdolan Mono","Perfalgan", 
              "Phenaphen","Phenaphen W/Codeine","Phenipirin","Phogoglandin","Pinex", 
              "Piramin","Pirinasol","Plicet","Polmofen","Predimol","Predualito",
              "Prodol","Prontina","Puernol","Pulmofen", "Pyregesic-C")

mixNames <- c("Liquiprin","Midol Maximum Strength","Midol PM Night Time Formula",
              "Midol Regular Strength" ,"Midol Teen Formula","Naldegesic",
              "Ornex Severe Cold Formula","Percocet","Percogesic with Codeine",
              "Propacet" )
```

failed attempt:

```r
#####STUFF THAT DIDNT WORK!!!!

# cross2(
#   .x = synonyms, .y = mixNames  #lists - each list has 2 lists - each of those is an atomic vector of 1
# ) %>% 
#   map_dfc(lift(str_detect)) #lift - modifies function to take a list of arguments - works for nested lists 

#this returns a df just like the apply 

# mix_syn_lgl_df <- map_dfc(
#   mixNames,
#   ~ map_lgl(synonyms, str_detect, pattern = .x)
# )

# colnames(mix_syn_lgl_df) <- mixNames
# 
# mix_syn_lgl_df$synonyms <- synonyms
```

This actually worked:

```r
#remove mixture names from synonyms

mix_syn_lgl_mat <- sapply(mixNames, function(x){
  str_detect(string = synonyms, pattern = x)
}) #returns a matrix 21x10 of logicals while preserving colnames

rownames(mix_syn_lgl_mat) <- synonyms #add synoyms as rownames
#create a new object with a new col of sum of TRUES in row
mix_syn_lgl_mat2 <- cbind(mix_syn_lgl_mat, rowSums(mix_syn_lgl_mat)) 
#take the numerical matrix mix_syn_lgl_mat2 and return the row names where the last col (rowsums) > 0
badNames <- row.names(mix_syn_lgl_mat2[mix_syn_lgl_mat2[, ncol(mix_syn_lgl_mat2)] > 0, ])
#filter out those names from the synonyms vector
pureSyn <- synonyms[!(synonyms %in% badNames)]
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Do you want to remove the matches from the `synonyms` vector (i.e., `"Percocet-5"    "Percocet-Demi"`), and return the rest of the `synonyms` vector?

Comment: @Andrew that's precisely what i am trying to do... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the `synonyms` vector without values that have any overlap with `mixNames`. You can subset `synonyms` to remove the matches. Here `str_c`/`paste` collapse `mixNames` to create a pattern with all the `mixNames`. Then you just use partial string matching (i.e., `str_detect` and `grepl` from there).

Here using `stringr` - which is slightly tidy-er

```
synonyms[str_detect(synonyms, str_c(mixNames, collapse = "|"), negate = T)]
```

Or using functions from base R:

```
synonyms[!grepl(paste(mixNames, collapse = "|"), synonyms)]
# OR
grep(paste(mixNames, collapse = "|"), synonyms, value = T, invert = T)
```

As a site note, if you want to check out alternate ways to match strings, look at `stringdist` or other string distance functions / packages.

Answer (score 0):

I like to build a `%g%` operator for stuff like this. The following creates a tibble containing the values from your code that *actually works*:

```r
library(tidyverse)

`%g%` <- function(x, y) {
  z <- paste0(y, collapse = "|")
  grepl(z, x, ignore.case = T)
}

tibble(syn = synonyms) %>% 
  filter(!syn %g% mixNames)
#> # A tibble: 19 x 1
#>    syn                
#>    <chr>              
#>  1 Pediatrix          
#>  2 Perdolan Mono      
#>  3 Perfalgan          
#>  4 Phenaphen          
#>  5 Phenaphen W/Codeine
#>  6 Phenipirin         
#>  7 Phogoglandin       
#>  8 Pinex              
#>  9 Piramin            
#> 10 Pirinasol          
#> 11 Plicet             
#> 12 Polmofen           
#> 13 Predimol           
#> 14 Predualito         
#> 15 Prodol             
#> 16 Prontina           
#> 17 Puernol            
#> 18 Pulmofen           
#> 19 Pyregesic-C
```

Similarly, to get only those that drugs in `synonym` that match a value in `mixNames`:

```r
tibble(syn = synonyms) %>% 
  filter(syn %g% mixNames)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   syn          
#>   <chr>        
#> 1 Percocet-5   
#> 2 Percocet-Demi
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>